# Less file changes not taken in production

Tags: magento2, less, less-css, static-content-deploy

In prod mode with Magento 2.0.5

Making changes to `app\design\frontend\mythemes\2016\web\css\source\_extend.less`

Then ,

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

CSS generated in `pub/static/` does not reflect the change.

Is it the right way?

Comment: I have a similar issue. Did you fix this one ? If yes , how ?

Comment: I can't remember if I solved this sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The cache files you are deleting look correct.

I was having a similar issue, and for me there was an issue in one of my .less files to do with a variable that was preventing it from being deployed. Are there any errors that are generated when you run the following?

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

I didn't need to add the **php** before my command to deploy, but that might just be a difference between our systems.

Answer (score 0):

You could not change direct less css files.

You find which css are you going to alter, Download and move it on theme
apply changes
and run

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

If needed run also

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```